# 「に対し 」と「に対して」の違い？

Tags: grammar, word-usage

While many parents are putting money aside for college tuition, some are taking on another big expense: buying cars for their teenagers.

(大学の授業料のためにお金をためている親は多いの**に対し**、10代の子供のために車を買うなどそれ以外にも多額の出費をしている親もいる)

John is quiet where his sister is lively.
(ジョンが物静かであるの**に対して**、彼の妹は活発だ)

二つは何の違いがありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `に対し` and `に対して` mean the same thing ('in contrast to', 'whereas', etc), but they differ in tone. Stylistically, `に対し` is more formal than `に対して` and is more likely to be used in written Japanese or formal styles of speech.